# Custom Types and Subtypes results in Oracle ORA-22800 after Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I have the following DDL creating a Supertype and a Subtype:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FOO AS OBJECT (
  name VARCHAR2(45))
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BAR UNDER FOO(
    additional_column NUMBER(10, 2)
    )
FINAL;

CREATE TABLE foo_table (
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  foo FOO,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Now when I do an insert on it:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo_table (id, foo) VALUES (1, BAR('baz', 10.0));
```

I get an `ORA-22800`.

*Edit: Well that's weird. With this example it works like a charm. Must be an issue from my database or the removed columns. Will investigate.

Solution: I used `NUMBER(100,2)` in my real code unlike in this example. Editing to `NUMBER(10,2)` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of your code on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53318651d0ec113aaaba2ff9fdda9067). As you can see, there is nothing wrong with your type definitions and we don't get ORA-22800.

What is wrong in your INSERT statement is:

- `"SUPERTYPE"` is not the name of the column you the INSERT projection should reference `"supertype"`
- You are passing three arguments when you try to instantiate `"SUBTYPE"` but the constructor is defined to expect only two.

The corrected version is

```
INSERT INTO supertype_table (id, "supertype") 
VALUES (2, "SUBTYPE"('bar', 10.0));
```

Comment: Whops! Sorry, that's my fault while simplifying the code. I'll edit the question. However the insert statement in my real code is correct.

Comment: Nope, still not [seeing that error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c428a567e5795282ea9cb1482bb904a7). Unfortunately, there's not much we can do to help until you can post a reproducible test case.

Comment: I found the issue. Unlike the example I provided I used `NUMBER(100,2)`, editing to `NUMBER(10,2)` solved it.

Comment: So the teaching is to make sure that the test case you post here *actually reproduces the problem*. Not only does that avoid wasting other peoples' time, frequently the act of creating such a test case produces a lightbulb moment in which we realise the solution ourselves,